# Create multiline jsx inside a function

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create a multiline jsx variable

```
returnedElem = <StyledRemovedAnnotationDiv>
      <p>{this.state.deletedAnnotation.objectRemoved.prediction}</p>
      <button
        className="btn btn-danger"
        onClick={() => this.undoDelete(tax, deletedObj)}
      >
        Undo
      </button>
    </StyledRemovedAnnotationDiv>,
```

But this is not working. Please guide me.

Comment: what kind of component is `StyledRemovedAnnotationDiv`? you ain't passing any props, are you? what do you mean by not working? what does the `undoDelete` function does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping with braces:

```js
returnedElem = (
  <StyledRemovedAnnotationDiv>
      <p>{this.state.deletedAnnotation.objectRemoved.prediction}</p>
      <button
        className="btn btn-danger"
        onClick={() => this.undoDelete(tax, deletedObj)}
      >
        Undo
      </button>
  </StyledRemovedAnnotationDiv>
)
```